# If statement second condition always executing

Tags: c++, string, struct

I have a struct called users containing username information:

```
struct User{
    string name;
    string type;
    int credit;
    bool loginState;
};
```

My program reads in a txt file and creates an array of User struct types called "users" to store all the data. Im trying to create a function that deletes a user, so in the for loop below I'm searching for the string

```
userName
```

in the users array. If the user name exists then all the information of that user account is stored in the User temp. Otherwise an error is generated stating that the user entered does not exist.

```
string userName;
User temp;    

cout<<"Please enter a username to delete:";
cin >> userName;

for(int i=0; i<usersSize; i++){
    if((users[i].name).compare(userName) == 0){
        temp.name = users[i].name;
        temp.type = users[i].type;
        temp.credit = users[i].credit;
        temp.loginState = users[i].loginState;
    }else{
        cout << "Error: User does not exist";
    }
 }
```

I've tested my program and no matter what the input is, whether the user exists or not, the if statement always outputs the second condition. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you debug to see what is the value of `users[i].name` and `userName` in the loop?

Comment: Your program will forcibly enter the second condition for each user that is different from `userName`. So if you have 2 users "John" and "Jim" and you want tlo delete "John", you will get the message "Error: User does not exist" for "Jim".

Comment: could be a case of case sensitivity

Comment: It will be helpful to post the code you are using to read your data and the contents of the file containing the data.

Comment: The code looks correct, I suggest you to check users content with a debugger. As @thebaconing pointed out C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: Exactly as @MichaelWalz said. Your code will work fine for an user who exists. But for the rest of the users it will repeatedly print "Error: User does not exist"..

Comment: on other note, you can simply write comparison as `users[i].name == userName`. No need to use `compare()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag to indicate that user found or not.. e.g;

```
bool flag=false;
for(int i=0; i<usersSize; i++){
    if((users[i].name).compare(userName) == 0){
        temp.name = users[i].name;
        temp.type = users[i].type;
        temp.credit = users[i].credit;
        temp.loginState = users[i].loginState;
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
 }
if(!flag){
        cout << "Error: User does not exist";
}
```

Hope it helped...

Answer (score 2):

You need to first check if the user exists and then process the user which was found. The problem in your code is that the for loop checks all users and shows a message for all users but the one that matches (if any).

Check this code:

```
bool userWasFound = false;
int i;
for(i=0; i<usersSize; i++){
    if((users[i].name).compare(userName) == 0){
        userWasFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

// If no user was found, 'userWasFound' will still be 'false' at this point

if(userWasFound){
    temp.name = users[i].name;
    temp.type = users[i].type;
    temp.credit = users[i].credit;
    temp.loginState = users[i].loginState;
}else{
    cout << "Error: User does not exist";
}
```